# изменение кодировки данных из базы Firebird QT 5.10

Tags: c++, qt

Qt 5.10
Как правильно конвертировать данные из базы данных Firebird. В базе данные хоронятся в кодировке win1251 в приложение приходят иероглифы.

```
db.setConnectOptions("ISC_DPB_LC_CTYPE=WIN1251");
```

не работает.

В Qt 5.10 не работает

```
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8");
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
```

Comment: у QSqlQueryModel весь интерфейс построен на QString — строках независящих от кодировки, так что не вижу, что тут можно было бы конвертировать... возможно неправильно заданы настройки соединения с сервером/хранения данных?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, не существует строк, независящих от кодировки. Внутри `QString` используется UTF-16, и при записи туда любых внешних строки происходит их перекодировка.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, и да, вопрошающему нужно преобразовать имеющийся в `QString` текст, скопировав его во внешний буфер с попутным преобразованием в Windows-1251. Однако я не знаю платформонезависимых способов это сделать.

Comment: Возможно, подойдёт ручное описание отображения юникодных символов в соответствующие коды Window-1251. Этак, через `std::map<QChar, char>`. А потом пробегать по символам в `QString`, сопоставлять каждый из них через тот `std::map` и записывать в итоговый буфер. Правда непонятно, что при этом делать с символами, отсутствующими в Windows 1251.

Comment: @Arhad, lol... это Qt, тут [всё украдено до нас](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html)

Comment: А пример можно как это работает?

Comment: @croll, что именно? да и из вопроса не понятно, что именно нужно...